# Is it OK to ask for review on exercise solutions that have been asked previously?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions, duplicates

I'm learning Rust and solve the problems/exercises from the book of Rust which have been solved by thousands of learners and posted on here by quite a few.

Last time I posted my code I received quite good feedback and learned a lot from it. But when I was posting my question, I noticed a lot of similar questions where some had the exact same title I tried to use.

While looking at those QAs taught me a lot, I couldn't learn from them exactly what I should do about my code, since solutions are mostly unique.

I'm going through the book and considering the quality I see around here, I intend to ask for reviews on my upcoming exercises. But before doing so, I wanted to make sure if this is OK on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

Code Review has very lax rules on duplicates.
I've only closed a handful, at most, of duplicate [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) questions over the years.

For example, we have 203 [fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) questions.
So your 'duplicate' is almost certainly ok.

Comment: thank you, much appreciate the straight forward answer :D